# Manually edited filenames don't reflect in Audio Station app on Synology DSM 411+

Tags: nas, synology

I ssh'd into my Synology NAS and performed a batch renaming operation on files and folders - doing it over the network seemed prohibitively expensive. I mainly used `find` and `mv`.

But somehow, the Audio Station and DS Audio app have not been notified of the changes. Any file or folder that was renamed is shown in the app, but clicking it just skips the item.

How can I force these apps to refresh their index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Synology support and they advised to reindex the media via Control Panel > Indexing Service > Media indexing > Re-index. I did and it fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Many, if not most audio file formats include meta informations IN the file.
This is the case for instance for mp3, flac, ...
Many audio rippers set the same values for file name and meta inside the file, as a band aid for old audio program that do not know how to read them.
What you are seeing is this information. You need a program to edit them.
It is a possibility for instance in many media players or through the file manager of windows.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am unable to understand how this is related to my question, though. Are you saying the DSM Audio Station app is using the audio metadata information to locate the audio file? I don't think this theory holds, because I have often manually edited the audio metadata on DSM without changing the underlying filename. Plus, folders don't hold audio metadata.